# including a script tag in an angular 5 component ng-content

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component that uses `ng-content`

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <div>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>`,
    selector: "drop-zone"
})
```

The ng-content is a template.

```
<drop-zone>
<script type="text/ng-template">
  <div id="template" class="file-row">
    ...
  </div>
</script>
</drop-zone>
```

I assume for security reasons, I cannot include `text/ng-template` script tags in the included code.

I need to provide drop zone with template `HTML` and providing a script tag of type `text/ng-template` is how this is typically done.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Why do you want to include a script dynamically as  a template ?

Comment: Have you tried [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31548311/8555393)?

Comment: @Niladri the template is used by dropzone.js to display file information as the files are dropped. My dropzone component should allow the component consumer to supply his/her own template to the component as they differ in each scenario.